# Adding a RadDatePicker to a custom RadGrid Form Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid, with the EditFormSettings set to Template. Within my `<FormTemplate>` I have a RadDatePicker that I need to databind.

My code:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpStartDate" runat="server" 
     SelectedDate='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>'>
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

"StartDate" references the column name in my DB. I have attempted to databind the control like this and get an error because the Bind() actually returns a string that cannot be stored in the SelectedDate field because it is of type DateTime.

How can I bind this AND convert this to a DateTime to be displayed in the SelectedDate property of my RadDatePicker on the Edit/Insert forms of my RadGrid?

Comment: What does your `StartDate` property returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

SelectedDate is the incorrect property to databind to, you must use the DbSelectedDate property.

```
DbSelectedDate='<%# Bind("Date") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `Bind`, but the following returns a DateTime object from a string:

```
<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("SelectedVal").ToString()) %>
```

I've tested in a `Textbox`

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("SelectedVal").ToString()) %>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: I added in this code:
SelectedDate='<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("StartDate")) %>'

That returns this error:
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments